# Spacing in Linear Layout not working as expected

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

A partner of mine created this xml layout and now I am trying to tweak it to look a bit more polished. Essentially, all I would like to do, is take the 4 buttons listed in the Linear Layout and reduce the vertical space between them, such that they are clustered closer to each other, but not touching, further up on the screen.

I've tried changing weights, gravities, etc...but nothing seems to work. Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:background="@drawable/brucehome"
    android:gravity="fill_vertical" android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/bonus" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="2sp" 
        android:padding="1sp" android:textColor="#0000FF" android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edges_shadow"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10sp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ch0"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2sp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edges"
        android:padding="10sp"
        android:textColor="#555555"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ch1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2sp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edges"
        android:padding="10sp"
        android:textColor="#555555"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ch2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2sp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edges"
        android:padding="10sp"
        android:textColor="#555555"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ch3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6sp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edges"
        android:padding="10sp"
        android:textColor="#555555"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/tryagain" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp" android:background="@drawable/rounded_edges"
        android:padding="12dip" android:textColor="#A52A2A" android:textSize="25sp"
        android:text="Try Again" />

</LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/ThumbRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" >
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/thumb" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:contentDescription="nevermind" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:padding="12dip">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scoreLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:padding="6dip"
        android:text="Score:"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="25sp" >

    </TextView>

    <Button android:id="@+id/ansopt" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edges" 
        android:textColor="#A52A2A" android:textSize="25sp" android:text="Show Answers" android:padding="6dip">
    </Button>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/score"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/scoreLabel"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/scoreLabel"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:padding="6dip"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the button layout like this, i mean layout_height should be "wrap_content":

```
   <Button
        android:id="@+id/ch2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2sp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edges"
        android:padding="10sp"
        android:textColor="#555555"
        android:textSize="25sp" />
```